# Attempting to associate my Club model with a User upon creation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models and I'm trying to associate the Club model to a User upon creation:

```
class Bag < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :clubs
 belongs_to :user
end

class Club < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :bag
 belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :bags
has_many :clubs, through: :bags
end
```

I have this in my `views/clubs/_form.html.erb`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <%= simple_form_for @club do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :brand %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, current_user.bags, :id, :title, prompt: "Please pick the bag that this club belongs to:" %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to set up my controller to make this association happen when I create a new Club?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nested attributes in rails. In this case, it should be one-to-many relation.

```
params: { club_name: "music", user_attributes:{user_id: 1}}

club = Club.create(params[:club])
club.user.id # 1
```

Please go to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have through association between Club and User. You could get the bag_id in params `params: { club_name: "music", bag_id: 1 }` using which build the club through association like

`club = current_user.bags.find(params[:bag_id]).clubs.build(params)`. Then you could do `club.save`

You've catch the Record not found exception which will be raised if the bag is not associated to the current_user.